# String convertion of function expression with parameters in Catch assertion

Tags: c++, catch-unit-test

If I run the following test witch [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch)

```
bool eq(int x, int y) {
    return x == y;
}

TEST_CASE("operator vs. function call") {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    CHECK(x == y);
    CHECK(eq(x, y));
}
```

I get the following output

```
/path/to/MyTest.cpp:8: Failure:
  CHECK(x == y)
with expansion:
  1 == 2

/path/to/MyTest.cpp:9: Failure:
  CHECK(eq(x, y))
with expansion:
  false
```

Why can Catch convert `x` and `y` to strings in the operator expression `x == y` but not in the function call expression `eq(x, y)`? Is it somehow possible to stringify the function call expression in a similar way to get output like this:

```
/path/to/MyTest.cpp:9: Failure:
  CHECK(eq(x, y))
with expansion:
  eq(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting part is [this](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/fe690a68ef1e41d08e90589480fa8190219aa5b0/include/internal/catch_capture.hpp#L47):

```
#define INTERNAL_CATCH_TEST( expr, resultDisposition, macroName ) \
    do { \
        Catch::ResultBuilder __catchResult( macroName, CATCH_INTERNAL_LINEINFO, #expr, resultDisposition ); \
        try { \
            CATCH_INTERNAL_SUPPRESS_PARENTHESES_WARNINGS \
            ( __catchResult <= expr ).endExpression(); \
            CATCH_INTERNAL_UNSUPPRESS_PARENTHESES_WARNINGS \
        } \
        catch( ... ) { \
            __catchResult.useActiveException( resultDisposition ); \
        } \
        INTERNAL_CATCH_REACT( __catchResult ) \
    } while( Catch::isTrue( false && static_cast<bool>( !!(expr) ) ) ) // expr here is never evaluated at runtime but it forces the compiler to give it a look
    // The double negation silences MSVC's C4800 warning, the static_cast forces short-circuit evaluation if the type has overloaded &&.
```

where `expr` is `x == y` or `eq(x, y)`.

**How it works for** `x == y`**:**
`__catchResult <= expr` results in `__catchResult <= x == y` which is equivalent to `(__catchResult <= x) == y` due to the lower precedence of `<=` compared to `==` (see [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)). `__catchResult <= x` wraps `x` in an object with an `==` operator, which `y` gets passed to. That's how `expr` gets destructured. All the rest is easy to imagine.

**Why it does not work for** `eq(x, y)`**:**

`__catchResult <= expr` results in `__catchResult <= eq(x, y)` and `eq(x, y)` is evaluated first (no destructuring).

For the same reason it does not work if the expression is surrounded by parentheses. For example, `(x == y)` would lead to `__catchResult <= (x == y)` in which case `x == y` is evaluated first (no destructuring). That's why `CHECK((x == y));` causes output

```
/path/to/MyTest.cpp:8: Failure:
  CHECK((x == y))
with expansion:
  false
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect once `CHECK` sees `eq(x, y)` it just sees the result of this function call as an expression.

You can insert a `INFO` before your `CHECK` to see the parameters to your function call:

```
INFO("x:" << x << ", y:" << y);
CHECK(eq(x, y));
```

which will be logged at the `CHECK` call (showing "with message"):

```
  CHECK( eq(x, y) )
with expansion:
  false
with message:
  x:1, y:2
```